# How can I convert this imperative style merge-sort implementation into functional style?

Tags: f#, mergesort

This is how I implemented merge-sort in F# using imperative style:

```
let merge (l1: List<string>,  l2: List<string>) = 
 let r: List<string> = new List<string>()
 let mutable (i,j, cnt1, cnt2) =  (0,0, l1.Count, l2.Count)
 while i < cnt1 && j < cnt2 do
    if l1.[i] <= l2.[j] then
        r.Add (l1.[i])
        i <- i + 1
    else
        r.Add (l2.[j])
        j <- j + 1

 if i = cnt1 then
    while j < cnt2 do
        r.Add (l2.[j])
        j <- j + 1
 else    
    while i < cnt1 do
        r.Add (l1.[i])
        i <- i + 1
 r
```

Can you convert this to alternate 'functional' styled implementation and explain how it works, if possible? Even though I am studying list comprehensions and all that at the moment, I can't come up with an idea to use it here.

Comment: Why would a sort-algorithm take two lists? Anyway, for your functional style implementation, I suggest you think of an recursive way to split a list and merge sorted lists.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a `List<T>`? These use arrays underneath, whereas F#'s built-in `'a list` is a linked list. The linked list makes it much easier to think recursively.

Comment: @Nodebody: This is just the "merging" part of the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using .NET `List<'T>` which is renamed to [ResizeArray<'T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) in F# to avoid confusion. If you use functional list, `merge` function would look like this:

```
let merge(xs, ys) =
    let rec loop xs ys acc =
        match xs, ys with
        | [], [] -> List.rev acc (* 1 *)
        | [], y::ys' -> loop xs ys' (y::acc) (* 2 *)
        | x::xs', [] -> loop xs' ys (x::acc) (* 3 *)
        | x::xs', y::_ when x <= y -> loop xs' ys (x::acc) (* 4 *)
        | _::_, y::ys' -> loop xs ys' (y::acc) (* 5 *)
    loop xs ys []
```

To explain this function in terms of your imperative version:

- The 4th and 5th patterns are corresponding to the first `while` loop where you compare two current elements and add the smaller one into a resulting list.
- The 2nd and 3rd patterns are similar to your 2nd and 3rd `while` loops.
- The first pattern is the case where `i = cnt1` and `j = cnt2` and we should return results. Since a new element is always prepended to the accumulator, we need to reverse it to get a list in the increasing order.

To be precise, your `merge` function is just one part of merge-sort algorithm. You need a function to split a list in two halves, call merge-sort on two halves and merge two sorted halves into one. The `split` function below is left for you as an exercise.

```
let rec mergeSort ls =
    match ls with
    | [] | [_] -> ls
    | _  -> let xs, ys = split ls
            let xs', ys' = mergeSort xs, mergeSort ys
            merge(xs', ys')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a more simple but naive alternative to pad's:

```fs
let rec merge x y = 
    match (x, y) with
    | ([], []) -> []
    | ([], rest) -> rest
    | (rest, []) -> rest
    | (fx :: xs, fy :: _) when fx <= fy -> fx :: merge xs y
    | (fx :: _, fy :: ys) -> fy :: merge x ys
```

Similarly to pad's, we're pattern matching over the function parameters.

- I first put them into a tuple so that I can pattern match them both at the same time.
- I then take care of the [base cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) with both or either of the parameters being empty.
- I then use `when` guard to check which first item is smaller
- I finally take the first item and cons it to the result of another call to `merge` with the rest of the items the smaller item was taken from and the whole of the other list. So if the first item of `x` is smaller, I append the first item of `x` (`fx` in this case) to the result of a call to `merge` passing in the rest of `x` (`xs`) and the whole of `y` (because the first item of `y` was larger).